# Basic doubt in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

How is $\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial \bar z} = \bar {\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}$?

I am confused about notation? pls clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, we have that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac 12 \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)$$ and

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac 12 \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right).$$ Thus

$$\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac 12 \left(\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial x} +i \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial y} \right)=\frac{\overline{\partial f}}{\partial z}.$$

Comment: Tq ...Sir ......